# Basic prolog issue with syntax of statement

Tags: prolog

I'm sort of a beginner to Prolog and I have a quick question. I've written a `sister_of/2` predicate that goes like this:

```
sister_of(X, Y) :-
    female(X),
    parents(X, Z, W) == parents(Y,Z,W),
    X \= Y.
```

I read this as X is a sister of Y if X is a female and the parents of X which are Z W are the same parents of Y, Z W and X and Y are not the same person. This isn't running for some reason though, so it must be a  syntax issue, some insight would be fantastic. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Prolog is not a *functional* language, it's a *relational* language. You define predicates (i.e. relations), not functions. Thus, your `parents(X, Z, W) == parents(Y,Z,W)` is just comparing two terms, `parents(X, Z, W)` and `parents(Y,Z,W)` for equality. Assuming that a `parents/3` predicate is also defined, you want something like:

```
sister_of(X, Y) :-
    female(X),
    parents(X, Z, W),
    parents(Y, Z, W),
    X \= Y.
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you began the construction of reasoning alright, but failed during the comparison. Here's what you've missed:

```
sister_of(X, Y) :-
    female(X),
    parents(X, Z, W),
    parents(Y, Z, W),
    X \= Y.
```

Now the reasoning goes as follows:

1. `X` is a sister of `Y`;
2. if `X` is a female;
3. if `X` has parents `Z` and `W`;
4. if `Y` has parents `Z` and `W`;
5. and, of course, `X` is not `Y`, so that `X` is not a sister of itself.

Notice that, the comparison you performed earlier is not necessary (and in fact, does not mean what you expected), since `Z` and `W` become limited to be the parents of `X` in step 3. This means that, `Z` and `W` already have a determined value after step 3 -- they are bound, in other words.

After that, in step 4, `Y` can only assume the same value of `X`, or some other value that makes `parents(Y, Z, W)` true. Finally, you remove the cases where `X == Y` in step 5, which gives you a valid definition of `sister_of(X, Y)`.